# Architecture: I have to make available object properties that that is updated every couple seconds

Tags: python, twisted

My app maintains the state of a bunch of objects with variables.

I'm using Twisted to accept socket requests and return the properties of an object.

I want to make sure the app can scale for a lot of requests so I'm wondering if I should deliver the object properties directly from the objects, or if I should store those properties in memcached or something similar, and have the requests read from that store.

I just wasn't sure if lots of requests reading the same object values would affect the performance of the part of the app that is managing those objects.

Am I over thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any performance penalty because of having many reading operations from the same object (only one thread is executed at a time after all).

Answer (score 0):

I think either you create an selfCreatedObject or using a memcached once, it will be an instance of python objects, like list or dict or anything else so the two ways are to same destination. 
I prefer to use object so you can make a check the change of the object value or validate it if needed.